# imagemin:dist task throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I've been attempting to solve this for over half the day now.

I have an angularjs project that I use grunt to build.

Running my `grunt` command give me the following:

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

```
Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
Total saved: 0 B

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2014-09-23 21:53:55 UTC)
loading tasks   7ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
svgmin:dist    58ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 89%
Total 65ms
    Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Fatal error: Object #<DestroyableTransform> has no method 'apply'


Execution Time (2014-09-23 21:53:55 UTC)
imagemin:dist  868ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 99%
Total 876ms Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

```

Here's my imagemin task in my GruntFile.js:

`imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }`

I can't find anything on the interwebs that helps me.  I did find this open issue, but no one has responded as of yet: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/254

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, png compression requires the `libpng-dev` library and I needed to install that on my build server using:

`sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

I also updated my package.json to use the latest grunt-contrib-imagemin ("^0.8.0")

Running `npm install` and `grunt` now work w/o errors.

Answer (score 2):

In short, I am using `Fedora` and my problem was solved by:

```
(sudo) yum install optipng
```

Here is the long answer.

This problem was [not obvious](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/254) because the error message does not tell much. It actually means one or more of the four dependencies was(were) missing:

```
gifsicle — Compress GIF images
jpegtran — Compress JPEG images
optipng — Compress PNG images
svgo — Compress SVG images
```

And those binaries are OS dependent.

The problem solving process is:

1. run the installation again to see what are not installed: `npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin`
2. google the failing component and see how that can be installed in your OS. Install all missing ones. (Well, if I should repeat step 1, I have gotten the same failure message, so for me it didn't help)
3. then try run imagemin task again. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

*imagemin* error through using `grunt serve:dist`-mode.

Try the following instead.

1. `npm uninstall`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm cache clean`
4. `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

As the author/@kevva of [imagemin commented on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/254#issuecomment-60069103) on `grunt-contrib-imagemin`, the problem is that the PR to update `mozjpeg` and other dependencies to the current version isn't yet in.

> You're using an unsupported version of imagemin-mozjpeg (grunt-contrib-imagemin doesn't support the stream based plugins yet). Try this `npm install imagemin-mozjpeg@1`
>
> ...
>
> Yeah, they work just fine with imagemin. But grunt-contrib-imagemin hasn't updated the imagemin dependency to 2.0.0 yet (just got merged yesterday in 04b8c10) so it's making use of an older API.